# Randomly slow inserts with InnoDB

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, amazon-rds

**TL;DR :** How can I improve insertion time in my table so that **every** inserts take under 100ms to perform?

This table is used by a webservice which receives transactions one by one so I can't group inserts. The timeout of the webservice must be under 150ms.

- **Infrastructure :** AWS
- **Application (php) :** EC2 t2.micro
- **Mysql :** RDS t2.small - 100GB magnetic storage

---

Here are the measurments I've done in production

[image: datadog]

**Top left hand corner :** We can see that a lot of inserts take more than 500ms and some even take more than 1s. Only a few are under 50ms. (red bars are 95th percentile)

**Top right hand corner :** RDS cpu is always low (memory usage is also constant and fine)

**Bottom left hand corner :** Number of inserts in the table

**Bottom right hand corner :** blue line is write IOPS, red line write lentency, blue bars is disk_queue_depth * 100. Disk queue is pretty much always below 1. We can see huge spikes in write lentency when everything else looks fine : no increase in IOPS nor in hardware ressource consumption.

I've created a script to measure insertion time in `account_transaction` in isolation :

```
// pseudo code
for ($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
    $ts=microtime(true);
    $db->insert(data);
    echo microtime(true)-$ts;
}
```

Output for 100 inserts : (sorted)

```
0.012468814849854
0.012633085250854
0.012740135192871
0.012858867645264
0.012872934341431
...
...
...
0.038048028945923
0.040112018585205
0.040735960006714
0.042028903961182
0.42462396621704
Avg : 0.025037434101105
```

I pretty much always end up with the same results : 1% or 2% of the inserts are very slow. Same if i perform 1000 inserts.

---

### What I've tried

- disable all indexes except PK : no improvements.
- rebuild all indexes : no improvements.
- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0` : great improvements :

  - slow inserts totally disappeared
  - average insert time 5 time faster
- switch to a bigger RDS (m4.large with 100GB SSD with 1000 IOPS preprovisioed) : some improvements :

  - slow inserts almost disappeared : maybe 0.1% if any and it rarely exceeds 100ms
  - average insert time 3 time faster

Unfortunately `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0` isn't an option as I can't afford to lose any transaction.

### My thoughts

I would expect inserts to be pretty fast most of the time (<1ms) even on basic hardware. Table only has 4 indexes and 200k rows. Am I wrong to assume that?

I suspect the bottleneck to be in the I/O realm because of the test with `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0` but the metrics I've got from AWS doesn't seem to confirm that. Am I wrong again?

### Table account_transaction

```
CREATE TABLE `account_transaction` (
  `id` char(21) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `seqid` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` char(21) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `token` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  ...
  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `processing_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`seqid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `consolidation_idx` (`trans_link`,`token`),
  KEY `idx_token` (`token`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=239304 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

`id` look like `1473430240HBCRSPL9FPB` = unix epoch + 10 random chars : we use this format vs a standard UUID to preserve good insert performance. Always 21 char.

`seqid` is used to keep track of the row number. Our `id` has a random part so we can't use it for that purpose.

`select count(1) from account_transaction` = 239k

### Questions

1. Is there a way to remove the high lentency spikes?
2. Should i go with bigger hardware to improve performance? My traffic is really low...
3. I must ensure that 99.9% of inserts are done under 100ms. Is that realistic on RDS mysql?

Comment: Should I ask this on SO instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I would suggest that you are 12ms away (latency) from the AWS datacenter.  You are stuck with that overhead.  Conclusion:  Beware of the timings.
- The "<1ms" is realistic only if client and server are in the same datacenter *and* the disk is SSD.  What is "magnetic storage"?  Perhaps that is an old, spinning, disk.  In that case 10ms is a reasonable guess for one write.  And it is hard to determine *from the available numbers* what the latency really is.  (Presumably less than 12ms.)  Conclusion:  Be sure to use SSDs.
- What does Amazon say about interference from other instances on the same hardware?  You have a "small" instance; there are probably many others sharing the same I/O.  If one of them has a spike, you might be slowed down.  With "large", you might have fewer competing customers.  And it might be SSD.  Conclusion:  Focus on average or 95th percentile, not spikes.
- `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1` *requires* at least 1 disk write per transaction.  `=0` delays and combines writes, hence the noticeable speedup.  One way to soften it is to batch multiple queries into a single `BEGIN`...`COMMIT`.  (Only do such where the logic makes sense.)  Conclusion:  Bigger transactions.  (However, you will still be stuck with 12+ms per *transaction* instead of per *insert*.)
- Updates to indexes (except for `UNIQUE` indexes) are delayed and can *usually* be treated as zero impact.
- `char(21) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` -- Is it always 21 characters?  If not, use `VARCHAR`.  Perhaps it is always ascii, not utf8?  If so, use `CHARACTER SET ascii`.
- `PRIMARY KEY (`seqid`),  UNIQUE KEY`id`(`id`)` -- Why have both?  As already mentioned, it causes overhead *included* in the `INSERT` time, namely to verify uniqueness before committing.
- The activity seems to be very low.  Normally people ask questions like yours when they are having trouble with hundreds or thousands of queries per second.
- Here's a way to get a 16-byte, chronologically ordered, UUID:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid .  (But not as easily displayed.)

Comment: That's what's troubling me. If inserts are that slow with 200k row and no traffic, what will it be with 10M rows? 100M? I'm trying to figure out if i'm doing something wrong or if these spikes are "normal". I've edited my post to add some information

Comment: Will you be inserting one row at a time?  From a single connection?  Each in a separate transaction?  Those add up to the 'worst case'.  You are currently running at 3M rows per day; is that not fast enough?  Batches of 100 rows per `INSERT` would get that to about 30M/day.

Comment: I cant do batch inserts. I receive transaction one by one and insert them with a new connection each time.

Comment: The connection time _may_ be longer than the `INSERT` time.  So, I think the whole question is focusing on the wrong thing.  Is this a web application?  If so, you can have multiple threads for allowing multiple "simultaneous" connections.  The threads would be overlapping, and even the `INSERTs` would be overlapping some, thereby further eliminating your worry about spikes.

Comment: Set up 20 threads in your web server; set up a test platform to send http requests as fast as you can (but ignore the returns).  Each web page would do a single insert.  Find out how fast the "system" can run.  Is that "fast enough"?

Comment: No it isn't. I have the requirement for my ws to respond in under 150ms (latency between my server and the client included). I was expecting answers like "you can't expect every insert to be under 100ms so you should make your ws async" or "Your inserts are way too slow for the hardware you have, here's what's wrong" or "Only way is to upgrade hardware. Your bench looks normal to me".

Comment: Any realistic "under xxx ms" must be accompanied by "xx% of the time".  Else it is impossible to meet.  Especially if you do not have full control of everything -- remember you are sharing a server, sharing a network, etc.  Your one test showed 43ms 99% of the time.